# Android Compat Support Library Linking

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-library, android-compatibility

I am trying to set up the android compatibility library with a project. I have downloaded the android \appcompat_v7_6 library and am still unable to add it --the library shows up with a red ex under References in Android (Properties).

Answer (score 0):

According to [android developers' guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) you should do as following if you are using eclipse.

Create a library project based on the support library code:

1. Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Library using the SDK Manager.
2. Create a library project and ensure the required JAR files are included in the project's build path:

   1. Select File > Import.
   2. Select Existing Android Code Into Workspace and click Next.
   3. Browse to the SDK installation directory and then to the Support Library folder. For example, if you are adding theappcompat project, browse to /extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/.
   4. Click Finish to import the project. For the v7 appcompat project, you should now see a new project titled android-support-v7-appcompat.
   5. In the new library project, expand the libs/ folder, right-click each .jar file and select Build Path > Add to Build Path. For example, when creating the the v7 appcompat project, add both the android-support-v4.jar andandroid-support-v7-appcompat.jar files to the build path.
   6. Right-click the library project folder and select Build Path > Configure Build Path.
   7. In the Order and Export tab, check the .jar files you just added to the build path, so they are available to projects that depend on this library project. For example, the appcompat project requires you to export both the android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar files.
   8. Uncheck Android Dependencies.
   9. Click OK to complete the changes.

You now have a library project for your selected Support Library that you can use with one or more application projects.
Add the library to your application project:

1. In the Project Explorer, right-click your project and select Properties.
2. In the category panel on the left side of the dialog, select Android.
3. In the Library pane, click the Add button.
4. Select the library project and click OK. For example, the appcompat project should be listed as android-support-v7-appcompat.
5. In the properties window, click OK.
   Note: If you are using the android-support-v7-mediarouter support library, you should note that it depends on theandroid-support-v7-appcompat library. In order for the v7 mediarouter library to compile, you must import both library projects into your development workspace. Then follow the procedure above to add the v7 appcompat project as a library to the v7 mediarouter library project.

Comment: I cannot find the support-v7-appcombat inside the SDK folder. I have imported all necessary files. Is there somewhere else the librarymight be?

Comment: right, I did download it. Currently the SDK manager shows no new downloads for the Android Support Library

Comment: you need to select from  SDK > extras > android > support > v7 > appcompat

Comment: the packages are visible in the Package Explorer. How can I get them into the application itself?

Comment: OMG I can't believe. Just follow the exact steps written above from beginning.